# Is there any existing modules on NLP

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, rdbms

can any one tell me whether any package is available in python to frame questions from nouns? and help me with similar projects.

Answer (score 0):

You could proceed using **Named Entity Recognition(NER)** that would let the system know the intent and entities of the query. For example:- **What is the capital of India?** Here you can name your **intent** to be **search_capital**. And your **entities** can be **"country":"India"**.
So the response of NER would give you intent and entity using which you can generate your SQL query. There are many libraries for NER for example:- RASA NLU (https://medium.com/rasa-blog/do-it-yourself-nlp-for-bot-developers-2e2da2817f3d), Spacy(https://github.com/explosion/spacy/blob/master/examples/training/train_intent_parser.py)
Now to generate SQL query, you could code the logic part that if a specific intent is returned, then call a specific function that would generate your query Or you can use Graql queries. You can go through a link for better understanding:-https://blog.grakn.ai/chatbots-and-grakn-ai-67563c64cfde

Comment: Let me know if there is anything else. These links helped me Thanks